# In TypeScript, is there a reason to prefer const foo: Type = {...} or const foo = { ... } as Type?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, there are two ways to declare that a constant is supposed to conform to an interface:

```
interface Foo { x: string; }
const HELLO: Foo = { x: 'hello' };
```

or

```
interface Foo { x: string; }
const HELLO = { x: 'hello' } as Foo;
```

These seem to have the same effect: TypeScript treats `HELLO` as having a type of `Foo`, and assigning it any members which don't appear in `interface Foo` results in an error.

Is there any reason to prefer one form vs. the other? Are they exactly equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for Typescript 2.1.4. I'm not aware of differences in other versions.

In the first one, you should get a compilation error if you were do do this:

```
interface Foo { x: string; }
const HELLO: Foo = { x:'hello', y: 'goodbye' }; // Will not compile.
```

In the second one, you're essentially casting it to interface `Foo`, so as far as compilation is concerned, this is perfectly valid.

```
interface Foo { x: string; }
const HELLO = { x:'hello', y: 'goodbye' } as Foo; // No compilation error.
const yValue = HELLO.y; // compilation error because "y" should not exist according to the interface
const yValue2 = (HELLO as any).y // suddenly works; yValue2 === "goodbye"
```

The former won't let you create the object with added data so it may prevent silly errors.  The latter will let you cast an already created object that has the same values as the interface. You can then pass that object to other functions or classes as if it's the interface. It will essentially hide the additional values.

Answer (score 8):

In your example, the assignment turns out to be the same. However, the functionality of typing a variable as in your first example and typecasting your variable, as in the second example are not the same.

Here is an extended example:

```
interface Foo { x: string; }
interface Foo2 extends Foo { y: string; }

// typing the variables
const hello: Foo = { x: 'hello' }; // works
const hello2: Foo2 = { x: 'hello', y: 'hello' }; // works
const hello3: Foo2 = { x: 'hello' }; // does not work because property 'y' is missing

// typecasting the variables
const hello4 = hello as Foo2; // works
const hello5 = hello2 as Foo2; // works
const hello6 = { x: 'hello' } as Foo2; // works

// typing the variables  
const hello7: Foo = {}; // does not work because property 'x' is missing
const hello8: Foo2 = {}; // does not work because property 'y' is missing
// typecasting the variables 
const hello9 = <Foo>{}; // works
const hello10 = <Foo2>{}; //works

// typing must match exact form, where typecasting does not, as long as interface is honored
const hello11: Foo = { x: 'hello', y: 'hello' }; // fails because of extra property 'y'
const hello12 = { x: 'hello', y: 'hello' } as Foo; // works
```

As you can see, typing the variable works only if the object assigned has an exact matching form. Typecasting the variable works even if the assign object is not valid, as it essentially means that you are telling typescript that you will make sure it does at some point.. for example if you initialize with an invalid object, and then using some logic set the remaining missing properties.

Typecasting can be done by using the `as` keyword or prepending the assigned variable with `<type>`.