# Can I specify a value type in TypeScript but still let TS deduce the key type?

Tags: typescript

If I create this constant in TypeScript:

```
const PARAMS = {
  green: {color: 0x007700},
  black: {color: 0x000000},
  white: {color: 0xffffff},
};
```

it deduces the type as `{ green: {color: number}; black: { color: number }; white: { color: number }; }`.

But I know from context that the type of the values should be `THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters`. I can declare this using an indexed type:

```
const PARAMS: {[name: string]: THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters} = {
  green: {color: 0x007700},
  black: {color: 0x000000},
  white: {color: 0xffffff},
};
```

but then I lose the specific possibilities for keys ("green", "black" or "white"). I can model it more precisely by writing out the full type that I want:

```
const PARAMS: {
  green: THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters,
  black: THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters,
  white: THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters
} = {
  green: {color: 0x007700},
  black: {color: 0x000000},
  white: {color: 0xffffff},
};
```

but this is quite verbose and repetitive.

Is there a way to get the the type I want in a more concise way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reduce the verbosity by using generic mapped type

```
type ParamsType<Colors extends string> = {
    [c in Colors]: THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters;
}

const PARAMS: ParamsType<'green' | 'black' | 'white'> = {
  green: {color: 0x007700},
  black: {color: 0x000000},
  white: {color: 0xffffff},
};
```

But you still have to repeat color names twice. If you want typescript to deduce keys, you have to introduce intermediate function, completely useless at runtime. I don't know of any other way to make typescript to infer generic parameter - [there is a proposal on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400) to allow deduction for default template parameter, but nothing was implemented so far.

```
function inferColorKeys<Colors extends string>(params: ParamsType<Colors>): ParamsType<Colors> {
    return params;
}


const PARAMS = inferColorKeys({
  green: {color: 0x007700},
  black: {color: 0x000000},
  white: {color: 0xffffff},
});
```

**UPDATE**

You can make it completely generic, as @jcalz suggested, by making `inferKeys` into a function that takes explicit generic parameter and returns a function that infers its generic parameter. It has to be two functions because a function can't have some generic parameters explicit and some inferred. Also, it makes use of built-in `Record` type which is  defined as
 `type Record<K extends string, V> = {[k in K]: V}`.

```
const inferKeys = <V>() => <K extends string>(x: Record<K,V>): Record<K,V> => x;

const PARAMS = inferKeys<THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters>()({
    green: {color: 0x007700},
    black: {color: 0x000000},
    white: {color: 0xffffff},
});
```

type of `PARAMS` is inferred as

```
Record<"green" | "black" | "white", THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters>
```

Comment: I like the `inferColorKeys` trick. Is it possible to make it generic, e.g. to let me write `const PARAMS = inferKeys<THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters>({ ... });` and not create the intermediate types?

Comment: It's not that easy because a function can't have some generic parameters explicit and some inferred. A way to bypass that is to add yet another intermediate function which takes explicit generic parameter, but when I try that typescript inference reverts to `{color: number`} instead of `THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters` for value types. Need to think more.

Comment: Maybe something like `const inferKeys = <V>() => <K extends string>(x: Record<K,V>): Record<K,V> => x;`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an option for you?

```
const PARAMS = {
  green: {color: 0x007700} as THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters,
  black: {color: 0x000000} as THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters,
  white: {color: 0xffffff} as THREE.MeshBasicMaterialParameters,
};
```

Comment: That's repetitive and also runs into this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964087/in-typescript-is-there-a-reason-to-prefer-const-foo-type-or-const-foo (I'd rather use `:` than `as`).